# use of insert and update attributes

Tags: hibernate

What is the use of insert and update attribute in property tag in hibernate ?

Answer (score 0):

> update, insert (optional - defaults to true): specifies that the mapped columns should be included in SQL UPDATE and/or INSERT statements. Setting both to false allows a pure "derived" property whose value is initialized from some other property that maps to the same column(s), or by a trigger or other application.

[Hibernate Reference Manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-property)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class User {

    private long idUser;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    //Constructor + getters + setters
}
```

Let's take this class, and supposing we have the mapping file written, but at the property tag of name we put **update="false"**, at the same time we enabled printing sql to the console.

Updating an object would give us the following output:

```
**Hibernate:  
/* update
        com.pojos.User */ update
            user 
        set
            age=? 
        where
            idUser=?**
```

Now removing the update attibute from the name's property tag and updating a user object again would give us the following output:

```
Hibernate: 
    /* update
        com.pojos.User */ update
            user 
        set
            name=?,
            age=? 
        where
            idUser=?
```

Et voilà! The same happens for insert statement!